# Why are heavy images not loading when we scroll down and scroll up

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am working on Roku app using Scene Graph component.
In my application first time images(posters) loaded properly but, when i scroll down and up, images(posters) are unable to load .
 *I observed that it happens only when heavy images*. Please provide suggestion to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Images are being freed from buffer when there is lack of memory and then loaded again.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply,  Is there any way increase buffer memory in roku.

Comment: What is the buffer limit?

Answer (score 1):

@vijaykumar - you can't "increase buffer memory".

Instead "lighten up" on your images. No "heavy" images!

It's quite common for people to abusive with image file sizes, not accounting for how low the TV resolution is - the 10ft experience is entirely different from PC monitor.

Unless line-art, use JPGs with higher compression and possibly undersized - but never oversized